# Ain't "the straw that brakes the camel's back" an example of a critical phenomenon, instead of chaotic behavior?

Tags: chaos-theory, critical-phenomena

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUsePzlOmxw) old but very interesting video (the part where they show two concentric cylinders, Couette cells, in which the visible liquid shows very strange behavior if the velocity with which the cylinders rotate varies is very interesting) about chaos it is said that when you put more and more weight on a camel's back there will come a point that when you place a tiny extra weight on it's back, the camel falls down (the straw that brakes the camel's back). It is said that this is an example of chaos.

But isn't this an example of a critical point of a system, i.e. that if you go above or below the value of this critical point, the system will show a change to a very different state? Like the critical mass of enriched Uranium? If the mass exceeds this critical value we all know what happens. Of course, a very little change of the initial conditions (like the mass on the back of the camel's back) is changed in a very small way, giving rise to the very different state of collapse instead of standing. Am I right that this **not** an example of chaotic behavior?

Comment: It's certainly critical behavior. If they talked about the specific _way_ in which the camel buckles afterward, that might be a good description of chaotic behavior. If not, it's not a very apt analogy.

Comment: I see what you mean about the different ways the camel can fall. That's indeed chaotic because a slightly different way the camel stands when he falls will result in a very big difference in how he (or she) ends up, lying on the ground. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: The video lasts 55 minutes. At what time-mark is the "straw that breaks the camel's back" analogy made?

Comment: Around 6 minutes and 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  Sensitivity to initial conditions is only one condition for [chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory).  Another condition is that the system needs to exhibit topological mixing.  Topological mixing means that if you take any set of states, and iterate enough times, you'll come across any other set.  If we think of the camel as having "standing" and "collapsed" sets, and we are in the standing set because we haven't put the last straw on the camel's back, we'll never reach collapsed.  Likewise, once we break the camel's back with the last straw, it will never return to standing.

It is possible that camels do indeed exhibit some chaotic behavior when falling, but I don't believe any such phenomena is well known, and its certainly not related to straws breaking their back.

Comment: What does one iterate and can you give an example where this iteration (when applied enough times), you'll come across the other set(s)?

Comment: In this case, it is the time-evolution function for the fall of the camel.  As a more chaotic example, consider the position/momentum state of a double pendulum.  No matter what states you start in, you can reach any other state (within energy limits) after some period of time.  In the case of the newton attractor, a known chaotic system, there are regions of the state-space where it doesn't matter how small of a circle you draw, it will contain points that go to every root of the newton attractor's equation.

Comment: @descheleschilder, One talks about iterations when the time takes discrete values, so the system state at a time $n+1$ is, e.g., a function of the state at the previous time: $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. For a continuous-time system (usually described by a differential equation), you'd say "wait for a long enough time" instead.